# Конвертирование из Optional в List

Tags: java

Все функции возвращают `List<Person>`. Но внутри функции есть переменная типа `Collection<Person>` и ее надо вернуть.

Но функция возвращает `List<Person>`.

Как привести `Collection<List<Person>>` к `List<Person>`?

Comment: В заголовке сказано об `Optional` в тексте ничего о нем нет

Comment: В тексте тоже в одном месте написано `Collection<Person>` в другом `Collection<List<Person>>`. Приведите примеры кода, распишите подробно какой нужен результат.

Answer (score 4):

Используйте метод [flatMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-).

```
Collection<List<Person>> input = ...;
List<Person> output = input.stream()
            .flatMap(Collection::stream)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```